# Adding 'Join Group' button in wordpress website

Tags: facebook, wordpress, wordpress-theming, facebook-group

I have a wordpress website and I have added my facebook group feeds to my wordpress site using custome facebook feed plugin. Now I need to add a 'Join Group' button to my website along with the group members face just like the facebook page like button. I need to embed my facebook group like that. Is there any way to do so? I have googled but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook does not offer a button/dialog for that. At most you could possible send an invite to the user via API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/members/#publish

Comment: Thank you.. I will have a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share the group to your Facebook page, click embed post, and copy the code over to Wordpress. This will give you the entire header and join button in Wordpress. I know this is an old post but maybe useful info for someone.

[image: FB Group Header]